# Argument not assignable to parameter of type T

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I have defined the interface `IDictionary` as follows:

```
interface IDictionary<T = any> {
  [key: string]: T;
}
```

And then later I pass this type **T** into the `db.update()` function which is defined as:

```
public update<T = IDictionary>(path: string, value: T) {
  return this.ref(path).update(value);
}
```

When I try to compile this file, I get the error that:

> src/shared/Model.ts (64,7): Argument of type '{ lastUpdated: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T'. (2345)

Considering the `IDictionary<any>` type is the default "T", I can't see why this wouldn't be considered valid. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

[image]

complete example that demonstrates the error:

```
interface IDictionary<T = any> {
  [key: string]: T;
}

function dbupdate<T = IDictionary>(path: string, value: T) {
  return this.ref(path).update(value);
}

abstract class Model<T = IDictionary> {

    public update(updateWith: IDictionary) {

        const reference = 'bar';
        return dbupdate<T>(
            reference,
            {
                ...updateWith,
                ...{ lastUpdated: 'baz' }
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is not in the code you posted but how you use it. The attached image doesn't show all of the relevant code, only the end of it. What is this `T`?

Comment: in the image above you can see the type resolution in the hovering dialog ... it is by default of type `IDictionary<any>`

Comment: Please update your question with the rest of the relevant code. It would be nice to have something that other will be able to use to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Ok, not sure what pieces to include so I've added the entire file to a **gist** here: https://gist.github.com/ksnyde/806b2e3439157d55bd0cf70c8ec5aa88

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Model` class declaration

```
abstract class Model<T = IDictionary> {
```

`T` is generic type parameter that can be anything. `IDictionary` is the default value, it does not imply that `T` will always be compatible with `IDictionary`. Nothing prevents someone from using your `Model` like this:

```
let myModel: Model<string> = ...
```

Typescript is telling you that in general case, the value you constructed for the second argument of `db.update` is not compatible with T.

The simplest way to make it compile is to change `db.update` call like this

```
    return dbupdate<IDictionary>(
        reference,
        {
            ...updateWith,
            ...{ lastUpdated: 'baz' }
        }
    );
```

However I have no idea what you are trying to achieve by having generic parameter `T`, so probably this is not the correct solution.

Comment: Model is the base class that other models inherit from so <T> would indicate the interface definition for the given concrete subclass. I think there is a way to leave type specificity off during the update though and have the typecasting take place elsewhere. So in a way I've solved my problem elsewhere but for intents of this question I feel you've addressed it well.